# Differentiation the form $\frac{dy}{dt}$ with respect to y.

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

It's been awhile since I took differential equations, so I am unsure if my manipulation is correct. Isn't it true that if we set $h(t,y)=y,$ then $h_{ty}=h_{yt}$? This would imply $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}0=0.$$

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your notation.  Is y a function?  Is it a function of t?  Is $h_{ty}$ the derivative of h with respect to t and y?  Is $h_{yt}$ the derivative of h with respect to y and t?  With your notation, what would the definition of $h_y$ be?

Comment: The variable $y$ is function of $t$, and $t$ alone. The notation $h_{ty}$ is $\dfrac{\partial }{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial }{\partial y}h$. Similarly for $h_{yt},$ we just swap the order of the differential operators.

Comment: What is given in the problem?  Is $h(t,y)=y$ and $h_{ty}=h_{yt}$ both given?

Comment: @NicNic8 Setting $h(t,y)=y$ was for convenience. We're not given that $h_{ty}=h_{yt},$ I just thought that the mixed partials were always equivalent. It's been years since I learned this stuff. We're given that $f=dy/dt$ and $f$ is smooth in $y$ as well as $t$. We're also given that $y$ is smooth. No other details are given.

Comment: My attempt would be to go via the inverse function, $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{1}{\frac{dt}{dy}}$, and to differentiate that with respect to $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without following your calculus, a straightforward method is :
$$\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)=\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{1}{\frac{dt}{dy}}\right)=-\frac{\frac{d^2t}{dy^2}}{\left(\frac{dt}{dy}\right)^2}$$
because to differentiate wrt $y$ we have to define which function of $y$ (not of $t$) must be considered. Thus it is not $\frac{dy}{dt}$ because this is a function of $t$. It is  $\left(\frac{dt}{dy}\right)^{-1}$ which is a function of $y$ as required.

Answer (score 2):

Setting h(t,y) to y appears bogus.
When y is a function of t, one usually writes y = y(t).
Then $y_y = 1$, not the zero you claim, though $y_{yt}$ = 0.
$y_t = y'$ since y is a function of t.
$y_{ty} = y'_y$ doesn't happen because y' is not a function of y.

Comment: Why is it bogus to write $h(t,y)=y$? I see the mistake of setting $y_y=0.$ If $y'$ is not a function of $y$, then how do you differentiate it with respect to y? My professor claims we can do this for homework.

Comment: @Melody.   h = y + 0t.

Comment: @Melody. d/dy dy/dt = d$^2$y/dt$^2$ × dt/dy.